# hbase select few column and apply filter

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I am new to hbase and trying to write below query in `hbase shell`

> Select f1,f2, sum(f3) from t1 where f1<3 group by f1,f2

OR

> Select f1,f2 from t1 where f1<3

I put the data into hbase

```
hbase(main):022:0> scan 't1'
ROW                                COLUMN+CELL                                                                                        
 1                                 column=f1:, timestamp=1473153098191, value=2                                                       
 1                                 column=f2:, timestamp=1473153106483, value=Ajay                                                    
 1                                 column=f3:, timestamp=1473153113917, value=90                                                      
 2                                 column=f1:, timestamp=1473153159384, value=1                                                       
 2                                 column=f2:, timestamp=1473153159422, value=Amit                                                  
 2                                 column=f3:, timestamp=1473153160329, value=92                                                      
 3                                 column=f1:, timestamp=1473153204785, value=2                                                       
 3                                 column=f2:, timestamp=1473153204847, value=Ajay                                                    
 3                                 column=f3:, timestamp=1473153205430, value=92                                                      
3 row(s) in 0.0240 seconds
```

I tried to use `MultipleColumnPrefixFilter` but not able to get the desired result.

Please help.

Comment: don't think filter can do that, how about run a map-reduce job?

Comment: ok.. understood..  HBase is not built for this type of functionality... I suppose simple filter we can do in hbase.. Please see the edits. `Select f1,f2 from t1 where f1<3`

Comment: even without aggregation, this query can't be supported by built-in filter, but a custom filter can do this job.